# Flickr carousel stretching image HTML, CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

please can some one help to figure out why the image not maintaining the aspect ratio. I've was looking for a Flickr script to my site and found one. But the main problem is that it cannot maintain the aspect ratio. 
Please help me obi wan, you are my last hope!

Script was found in this site:
https://github.com/blackfalcon/flickr-carousel/blob/master/index.html

To help identify the issues i've uploaded it to my site as index2:
http://scorpion3d.com/index2.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <title>Flickr API Carousel</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
            html,
            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
            }
            html {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            }
            *, *:before, *:after {
                box-sizing: inherit;
            }
            a {
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .carousel-box {
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .action-buttons {
                width: 100%;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                position: absolute;
                top: calc(50% - 100px);
                z-index: 1;
                opacity: .1;
                transition: opacity .25s ease;
            }
            .carousel-box:hover .action-buttons {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .action-buttons button {
                border: none;
                font-size: 50px;
                padding: 0 10px;
                display: block;
                background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
                height: 1.2em;
                line-height: 1;
            }
            .action-buttons button:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .carousel-content {
                height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
            [data-function="slide"] {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                opacity: 0;
                transition: opacity .25s ease;
                display: flex;
                align-items: flex-end;
            }
            [data-function="slide"] p {
                letter-spacing: 3px;
                padding: 1rem 40px;
                width: 100%;
                color: white;
                font-size: 2.5rem;
                z-index: 10;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            }
            .carousel-content img {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: -90%;
                right: 0;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            [data-function="slide"].current-slide {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            .album-info {
                color: white;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                font-size: 1rem;
                z-index: 10;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 1rem;
            }
            .album-info > a {
                margin-right: 1rem;
                padding-right: 1rem;
                border-right: 1px solid white;
            }
            @media screen and (min-width: 568px) {
                .carousel-content img {
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    overflow: auto;
                }
            }
            @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
                .action-buttons button {
                    font-size: 100px;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="carousel-box" id="carouselBox">
            <div class="action-buttons">
                <button class="prev" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" title="use left arrow key">
                    &#10094;
                </button>
                <button class="next" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" title="use right arrow key">
                    &#10095;
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="album-info">
                <a id="albumLink" target="_blank"><span id="albumInfo"></span></a>
                <span>Photos by <a id="albumOwnerLink" target="_blank"><span id="owner"></span></a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-content" id="carouselContent"></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Flickr configurations
            // Obfuscated API key var for demo
            const _0x6e6e=["\x65\x66\x63\x38\x33\x64\x63\x63\x64\x37\x63\x31\x64\x30\x61\x65\x39\x33\x66\x34\x61\x61\x37\x61\x66\x62\x39\x37\x31\x66\x63\x65"];const apiKey=_0x6e6e[0]
            // To personalize app, replace with your own API key
            // const apiKey = '';
            const album = '72157688964206172',
                albumOwner = '154845055@N05',
                flickrUrl = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/',
                method = '?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=',
                perPage = '20',
                formatCallback = '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1',
                contentContainer = document.getElementById('carouselContent'),
                oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            // Handle a response from the Flickr API
            function reqListener () {
                const flickrPhotos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(flickrPhotos.photoset);
                // Parse response for album and owner information
                const ownerName = flickrPhotos.photoset.ownername,
                    albumTitle = flickrPhotos.photoset.title,
                    albumUrl = 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/' + albumOwner + '/albums/' + album,
                    albumOwnerUrl = 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/' + albumOwner;
                // append response data to HTML DOM elements
                albumInfo.innerHTML = albumTitle;
                owner.innerHTML = ownerName;
                albumLink.href = albumUrl;
                albumOwnerLink.href = albumOwnerUrl;
                // Iterate through flickrPhotos in the response
                flickrPhotos.photoset.photo.forEach(function(foto) {
                    // Generate the URL for individual photo based on template
                    const url = 'https://farm' + foto.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + foto.server + '/' + foto.id + '_' + foto.secret + '.jpg';
                    const photoTitle = foto.title;
                    // Generate the necessary slide markup
                    //   <span data-function="slide">
                    //       <p>title</p>
                    //       <img src="" />
                    //   </span>
                    const span = document.createElement('span'),
                        img = document.createElement('img'),
                        title = document.createElement('p');
                    // append response data to generated HTML DOM elements
                    img.src = url;
                    img.alt = photoTitle;
                    title.innerHTML = photoTitle;
                    span.dataset.function = 'slide';
                    span.appendChild(title);
                    span.appendChild(img);
                    // Now append the new slide to the slide container
                    contentContainer.appendChild(span);
                });
                // Remote API request has been made and processed, initialize the carousel.
                flickrCarousel();
            }
            // API call to Flickr
            oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
            oReq.open("GET", flickrUrl + method + apiKey + '&photoset_id=' + album + '&user_id=' + albumOwner + '&per_page=' + perPage + formatCallback);
            oReq.send();
            // Carousel function
            function flickrCarousel () {
                // set scoped variables
                const carouselBox = document.getElementById('carouselBox'),
                    prev = carouselBox.querySelector('.prev'),
                    next = carouselBox.querySelector('.next'),
                    slides = carouselBox.querySelectorAll('[data-function=slide]'),
                    deck = slides.length;
                let slide = 0,
                    currentSlide = slides[0];
                // Find current slide of array and add selector
                currentSlide.classList.add('current-slide');
                // slider function
                function pushSlide(flip) {
                    // Use value of array to find node and remove selector
                    currentSlide.classList.remove('current-slide');
                    // Using value of current slide, add flip value to determine next slide value
                    slide = slide + flip;
                    // allows for full rotation of carousel; if 0 set value to -1 of array length
                    if (flip === -1 && slide < 0) {
                        slide = deck - 1;
                    }
                    // allows for full rotation of carousel; if max length of array, set to 0
                    if (flip === 1 && !slides[slide]) {
                        slide = 0;
                    }
                    // determine active slide and add selector
                    currentSlide = slides[slide];
                    currentSlide.classList.add('current-slide');
                }
                // Bind click events to toggle buttons and pass in slide flip value
                next.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    pushSlide(1);
                });
                prev.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    pushSlide(-1);
                });
                // Bind keyboard events to slide triggers
                document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
                    if( event.keyCode == 39 ) {
                        pushSlide(1);
                    }
                    if( event.keyCode == 37 ) {
                        pushSlide(-1);
                    }
                });
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned the height of the image to be 100% while defining ".carousel-content img" class.Try as below :

```
.carousel-content img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -90%;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Edit**

The general thing to be kept in mind while working with the image :

- we must not change the proportion of the image to prevent it from being distorted. hence, we can work either on width or on height, keeping the other one set to "Auto".
- Definitely, the image will settle itself according to what we have defined for its width and height. So if there won't be enough space to accommodate the whole image, the part of it will be cropped of ( or you say, stays hidden )

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply. Now images are not stretched, thank you! But now image has been cropped, i mean legs are missing from the photos.